# Regarding Android CTS Error

Tags: android

How to kill a running ANDROID CTS instance.Suppose one CTS instance is running on a terminal and if we abruptly close that terminal, that CTS instance will not be closed and when we try to start CTS again in a fresh terminal,we get this error[CTS_ERROR >>> Error: CTS is being used at the moment. No more than one CTS instance is allowed simultaneously] so how to go to CTS Host this time or kill this running instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$ ps -ef | grep "startcts"** then it will print the username, pid and other info for currently running CTS. Now use **$ kill -9 <PID>** to terminate the CTS.